# Delphi: unnecessary column lines & no RowSelect in List View (SysListView32)

Tags: delphi, listview, styles, selection

There is a **list view** with a **style** (thanks to Sertac Akyuz for a solution:) )

```
ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(ListView1.Handle, LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER);
```

But now a list view has two lacks: unnecessary column blue lines and rows are cannot be selected even if `RowSelect:=True;`. Rows are selected if to select Items, it doesn't work for Sub Items.

If to do `GridLines:=True` then a grid won't appear, something happens to a list view's background...

[image]

If to draw items with `OwnerDraw` then lines don't appear but only under items. I can paint a whole background, but is it the easiest way to hide those blue lines?

Can I handle these?

Thanks for your valuable answers!

Comment: Is seting the extended style the only change you made before the unwanted behaviour started? Ie if you remove the `ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle()` call, then selection works again and those blue lines dissappear etc?

Comment: @ain, right!If I remove the ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle() call, then selection works again and those blue lines disappear!

Comment: Try does using `ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(ListView1.Handle, ListView_GetExtendedListViewStyle(ListView1.Handle) + LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER);` make any difference.

Comment: @ain, excellent, thanks!!! Rows are selected now!!!! Only lines still appear...:(

Comment: For RowSelect: `ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(ListView1.Handle, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT or LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER);` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931938.aspx

Comment: @ain - That at least answers one of the questions, I guess you can post it as. FWIW, I don't see the blue lines here for the other question..

Comment: @maxfax - ain's comment is still better if you don't want to keep track of all the EX_ styles that the VCL could set (grid lines, hot track etc..)

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz, what Delphi do you have? I have the same on XE and 2010

Comment: @maxfax - Tested with D2007 on XPSP2. My not seeing blue lines does not mean there's no such problem BTW, it just means that I can't duplicate it here, I definitely see the lines in your picture.. *edit* now tested on vista and I see them (gray lines here), in fact they're there with the SysListView32 of a folder view also..

Comment: I have Windows 7. I'll ask a question about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call

```
ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(ListView1.Handle, LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER);
```

you unset all other extended style flags, seting only `LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER` on. So use

```
ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(ListView1.Handle,
    ListView_GetExtendedListViewStyle(ListView1.Handle) or LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER);
```

to preserve existing flags.

The vertical lines are probably a product of the VCL's effort to imitate a system listview as much as possible. When themes are enabled, VCL calls [`SetWindowTheme`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the listview passing 'explorer' as 'SubAppName' parameter, so the vertical lines you can see in an explorer folder view is duplicated. To undo that, you can call the function again yourself:

```
  SetWindowTheme(ListView1.Handle, nil, nil);
```

Note that you might not like what the listview becomes :).

Comment: @ain: Shouldn't it be `or` instead of `+`?

Comment: @Ulrich Both are OK (do the same thing), use one you prefer.

Comment: In **this** case, they do the same thing. In similar cases only `or` is correct. So I think one should get into the habit of using the one that breaks more seldom.

Comment: When dealing with this kind of bitmasks they are the same. And all API parameters are similar bitmasks, otherwise they wouldn't work (each option / style is only one unique bit). But actually I agree that using `or` is "cleaner code".

Comment: ain - Instead of providing another answer for a completely different question of the original question, I modified your answer. Please feel free to revert if you don't like it for any reason..

Comment: Guys, thank you for your help. Now I have really an amazing list view! Your help is very very valuable.